# Horizontal Calendar Set date

Tags: android, datetime

Currently, I am using this library
   https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar

The problem I am facing is that I need to show only 7 days ahead and 7 days back from the current date.

Not getting how I will manage the start date and end date to achieve the logic

Thank you guys in advance

The code I have tried is,

```
Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //end date
endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //start date
startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);

final Calendar defaultDate = Calendar.getInstance();
defaultDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);
horizontalCalendar = new HorizontalCalendar.Builder(this, R.id.calendarView)
        .startDate(startDate.getTime())
        .endDate(endDate.getTime())
        .datesNumberOnScreen(5)
        .dayNameFormat("EEE")
        .dayNumberFormat("dd")
        .monthFormat("MMM")
        .showDayName(true)
        .showMonthName(true)
        .defaultSelectedDate(defaultDate.getTime())
        .textColor(Color.LTGRAY, Color.WHITE)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` property,

```
Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance(); // End date
endDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);

Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance(); // Start date
startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);

Calendar defaultDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: Yes it's working but the default selected date is showing wrong now.it is moving to the starting date not the current date

Comment: Set the defaultDate as todays date. Remove `defaultDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);` this line. Check the edit.